# SQLite Unix timestamp getting dates older than 2 days ago

Tags: sqlite, datetime, where-clause, unix-timestamp

I have a field in my SQLite DB called created_date and I want to return all the results that are greater then 2 days ago.

I run this:

> SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', "created_date"/1000, 'unixepoch')
>   FROM Logs

I get the results showing in proper datetime format but when I add this to the end:

> where created_date <= datetime('now','-2 day')

all 10 results return.

```
created_date, created_date as datetime
1552143373, 2019-03-09 21:44:55 55.000
1552143373, 2019-03-09 21:44:55 55.000
1552143373, 2019-03-09 21:27:38 38.000
1552143373, 2019-03-09 21:29:19 19.000
1552143373, 2019-03-09 21:30:06 06.000
1552143373, 2019-03-09 21:30:10 10.000
1552143373, 2019-03-09 21:41:28 28.000
1552143373, 2019-03-09 21:42:40 40.000
1552143373, 2019-03-09 21:43:25 25.000
1552143373, 2019-03-09 21:50:07 07.000
```

Comment: `where created_date <= datetime('now','-2 day')` means dates that are older than 2 days ago, right?

Comment: If `created_date` is a Unix time, you either need to compare it to another Unix time value, or convert it to a string of the same format as the timestamp you are comparing it to. Trying to compare apples to oranges doesn't work.

Comment: If you want results for the last 2 days (last 48 hours): `where created_date >= datetime('now','-2 day')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

datetime() function returns "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" - https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

So use `strftime('%s','now','-2 days')` to get an integer'ish string for comparison.

Comment: When I add this I still get the results, at what point would I only get partial results?
for example if I set it to -1 days ago I still get the results also

Comment: try to run select `select strftime('%s','now','-2 days');` and see what you get and if it's comparable with the data you have in your table.

Comment: If your data is multiplied by milliseconds, you should divide it before comparison; `strftime(%s` returns timestamp in seconds.

Comment: If I run this

SELECT created_date, strftime('%s','now','-2 days') from Logs

I get this

1552167895827, 1552145309

Comment: See previous comment. You forgot /1000.

Comment: Ok, now you can try comparing them. Just to be on the safe side, add `+0` to strftime to make sure it's not comparing as strings: `created_date/1000<strftime('%s','now','-2 days')+0 `

Comment: Ok if I run this
SELECT created_date/1000, strftime('%s','now','-2 days'), created_date/1000<strftime('%s','now','-2 days')+0 from Logs
I get 
1552167895 1552145633 0

I really hate these long numbers lol

Comment: Alright I think I understand what you were showing me I ran this

SELECT strftime('%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S', created_date/1000, 'unixepoch'), created_date/1000 , strftime('%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S = %s','now','-2 days'), created_date/1000<strftime('%s','now','-2 days')+0 from Logs

and it returns 0 results but when I change it to this

SELECT strftime('%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S', created_date/1000, 'unixepoch'), created_date/1000 , strftime('%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S = %s','now','-1 days'), created_date/1000<strftime('%s','now','-1 days')+0 from Logs

they all return true.

Thank you for the help.